# What's the best way to detect if an IDataReader is empty?

Tags: c#, ado.net

It seems like IDataReader.Read() is always true at least one time (If I'm wrong about this let me know.)  So how do you tell if it has no records without just wrapping it in a try/catch?

Comment: Ben is correct. If an IDataReader is reading from an empty row set then the first call to Read() will return false (assuming the specific implementation you're using is written correctly).

Comment: That makes no sense. If read is supposed to indicate whether there are more rows, then it cannot represent an empty condition. For example, returning false on first read does not indicate an empty set. It indicates there are no more rows after the first record has already been read.

Comment: @Triynko: IDataReader.Read does **not** indicate there are more rows, it indicates a read attempt was successful. And the first call to it can (and not infrequently does) fail. And when it does fail, that does indicate that the set was empty.

Comment: IDataReader.Read will return false if the result set is empty, Read does just what it says, it attempts to Read a row from the result set, the results of which can then be accessed via idatareader[columnIndex] or idatareader[columnName].

Answer (score 23):

```
if(dr.Read())
{
   //do stuff
}
else
{
 //it's empty
}
```

usually you'll do this though:

```
while(dr.Read())
{
}
```

Comment: This is what I've tried, but it seems that the condition is always true at least once, but then if try to extract a value from the reader it throws an error.

Comment: Be careful of this, `Read()` [advances the reader to the next row](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx). So it doesn't **just** check if the datareader contains data

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if you want to use the interface then Read until false is the only way to test. If you are looking for a generic `IDataReader` implementation, you could try `DbDataReader` and use the `HasRows` property.

Comment: DbDataReader is an abstract class

Comment: @aku: Yes, that's the point. IDataReader is an interface that is (usually) implemented by a datareader of type whatever which derives from DbDataReader, which in turn implements IDataReader.

Comment: In reality, you'll never call `Read() ` on an `IDataReader` _object_ anyway, since there's no such thing. And in pretty much all actual implementations you'll get back an object which is a `DbdataReader`. So unless you got classes 'downgrading' that back to `IDataReader` as their return type, you can just call that. And even if it does get downgraded, it's worth checking: `if (reader is DbDataReader) return ((DbDataReader)reader).HasRows`

Answer (score 3):

You can just cast `System.Data.IDataReader` to `System.Data.Common.DbDataReader`

```
using (System.Data.IDataReader IReader = ICommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (((System.Data.Common.DbDataReader)IReader).HasRows)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
} // End Using IReader
```

It's pure evil, but it (usually) works ;)

(assuming your instance of `IDataReader` is implemented by a custom ADO.NET provider, and not some custom silly class of yours which just implements `IDataReader` instead of deriving from `DbDataReader` [which implements `IDataReader`]).

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled across this problem and came up with this...

```
bool isBeforeEoF;

do
{
    isBeforeEoF = reader.Read();

    if (isBeforeEoF)
    {
        yield return new Foo()
        {
            StreamID = (Guid)reader["ID"],
            FileType = (string)reader["Type"],
            Name = (string)reader["Name"],
            RelativePath = (string)reader["RelativePath"]
        };         
    }

} while (isBeforeEoF);
```

Answer (score 0):

IDataReader.Read **will** return false when first invoked when the result set is empty (say your query was `select 1 from sys.tables where 1=2`).

IDataReader.Read does just what it says, it reads a row from the resultset. Read is not a *pure* function and has side effects. In particular it changes its internal state so that the next call to Read will attempt to read the next row in that resultset.

An occasional issue with that is that if you **then** want to pass the IDataReader to a function, that function must expect that Read has previously been called.  Mistakenly calling Read twice without processing the first row will lead to loosing the first row of data with no way to recover (you can’t unread a row).

The problem arises because you may have some functions that have a body that has

```cs
while(IDataReader.Read())
{
}
```

and other functions that have

```cs
do 
{
} while (IDataReader.Read());
```

And if you mistake one for the other, you’ll get unexpected results.

This is in contrast to NextResult, which you must **not** call without first looping through all relevant rows in the first resultset.